# What's the advantage of using SDWAN over MPLS/Circuit Lines?

Tags: mpls, sd-wan

I am trying to figure out. What's the advantage of using SDWAN over MPLS/Circuit Lines?
Some Companies goal is to reduce costs so they migrate MPLS/Circuit Lines to SDWAN. Is there any engineering impact on the services? Better Performance or is it just related to costs?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to go back through the SD-WAN Design guide. Some particular notes that I pulled out is this:

Path Quality

BFD is used not only to detect blackout conditions but is also used to measure various path characteristics such as loss, latency, and jitter. These measurements are compared against the configured thresholds defined by the application-aware routing policy, and dynamic path decisions can be made based on the results in order to provide optimal quality for business-critical applications. [SD-WAN Design Zone](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/CVD/SDWAN/cisco-sdwan-design-guide.html)

As stated by Batuhan Mutlu, it allows for the utilization of multi-path links but also allows traffic to be preferred based on metrics (similar to MPLS-TE) while taking into account links that are not capable of TE like characteristics.

Comment: With SDWAN, you (or your controller) has the total say on how things go where. MPLS puts all traffic flow in the hands of the carrier(s).

Answer (score 4):

I think its mostly related to cost, Perhaps the greatest selling point for SD-WAN is the ability to cost-effectively mix and match network links according to content type or priority. Both internet broadband and cellular connections are less expensive than MPLS, so customers can choose those links instead of the expensive MPLS network for certain types of lower-priority traffic.